# CGrectMake width automatic on different devices

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ipad-mini

I know how to set the width of something like the navigation bar, for ipad mini `CGRectMake(0,0,748,100)` for example for a custom navigation bar, however the resolution for the ipads width is around double that, is there a way that will work on either device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you width in points:

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.width
```

You can get width in pixels multiplying it by `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`

Answer (score 0):

You can use autoresizingMask:

```
navControl.navigationBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```